# Does the phrase "perceived slight" indicate a slight is not real?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Can the phrase "perceived slight" be used to mean any slight a person perceives, whether that slight is grounded in reality or not, or is it synonymous with an "imagined slight" (a slight that is *only* perceived and not real)?

Comment: It’s used for an imagined slight

Comment: 'Perceived slight' does usually mean 'imagined' or 'unintended' but it's rather more complex a matter than that, because a 'slight' unlike an 'insult' is often subtle or ambiguous. Moreover a 'perceived slight' is the same as a real one as far as the perceiving party is concerned, and therefore can have more or less the same outcome depending on their response. **Example:**  Neither Tom nor Edward played football at school - while Tom said 'sports is for simple folk', Edward said he preferred to focus on his music. *Both boys were equally disliked by football players for the perceived slight.*

Comment: @EnglishStudent - Edward did no slighting there, and Tom pretty much outright called the football players *simple folk* so that’s not a perceived slight in either case.   Someone not saying hello to the party host before they left could be seen as a slight but if it was done because the guest had to suddenly rush to the hospital it would only be a perceived slight because it wasn’t intentional.

Comment: I take "perceived slight" to mean one which we don't have to have an objective opinion on.

Comment: @Jim as I said, unfortunately the football players 'perceived' **both** as a slight... I an just making an example of contrast to suggest the point that 'the slight lies in the mind of the perceiver' -- whether or not any slight was intended!

Comment: @EnglishStudent - ok.  I just don’t see how they could perceive a slight with respect to Edward’s statement.  My point was that an omniscient narrator would not call a real slight a *perceived* one, only an unintended one.

Comment: So a narrator would say, “The football players did not take kindly to Tom’s slight against them.” and “the party host was irritated by the perceived slight and huffed that next time she wouldn’t even invite them.”

Comment: @Jim you are very right that the slight was real in Tom's case, but (in this fictional example, because of a **mis**perception) a slight was ***unintended yet perceived*** in Edward's: that makes it a 'perceived slight'. So in the interest of perfect accuracy I would reword my last sentence as "The football players didn't like Tom for good reason, but they equally disliked Edward for the *perceived slight*"

Comment: It's slightly real.